# How to Catch Duplicate Entry in Primary Key with custom message in VB.NET instead of default exception msg

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, try-catch

I know that I will need to search for primary key value first in SQL server DB then if value is already there show a msg that record already exists else insert record in DB 
It would be something like this:

```
Dim matchISBN As string = txtISBN.Text

        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT isbn WHERE isbn =" & matchISBN, cn)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        If isbn = matchISBN Then messagebox.show("record already exist")
        else ....
```

Insert record

I can handle it using try & catch but try & catch will show default message I want my own custom message only for duplicate primary key value! 
I don't know how to code this any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does `SELECT isbn WHERE isbn=` returns only single row??

Comment: @wingedpanther yeah it is a primary key and I would like to check if ISBN already in DB or no

Comment: Since your returning a table `dt` check the rowcount. If its > 0 u have a dup...

Comment: @Codexer thank you it worked

Comment: Welcome knew it would... sometimes the smallest changes/fix is right there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this(IMO,you no need to use `Try-Catch` to handle it ),

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim retval As Object
    With cmd
        .Connection = GenConnection()
        .CommandText = "select id from gmtab08 where id=1440"
        retval = .ExecuteScalar
    End With
    If retval Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Not Exists")
    Else
        MsgBox("Exists")
    End If
```

---

Or

```
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Exists")
        Else
            /*'Your code*/
        End If
```

Comment: Sure will... The first example may not return a record therefore it will bomb when calling a IsDBNull function on the ExecuteScaler if no row is returned. Secondly you have the return as an object which may be nothing and then trying to use it to see if it equals 0, but maybe will be nothing. Also with option StrictOn using `If retval = 0` would throw up as the datatypes your comparing are different... if your looking for quick points at least check this stuff... and yes he would need try catch if using the first code...

Comment: @wingedpanther somen else down voted you, I up voted and marked your answer as correct, it solved my problem thank you

Comment: others looking for the right answer this worked for me:                           If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Exists")
        Else
            /*'Your code*/
        End If

Comment: What if thers no record, thats not null thats nothing... completely different...IsDBNull is to check an object for null not nothing...

Comment: @Codexer Yes, correct... I've revamped the answer, `retval` can handle any datatype no matter if it is `Nothing` or `Integer`